# Building WysiHat from source?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, 37-signals

I'm trying to build 37 Signals' WYSIWYG javascript framework from [its source](https://github.com/37signals/wysihat). (I'm not a rails developer but I thought this would be fairly easy).

The instructions read:

> You can build the latest version of
>   WysiHat from source by running rake
>   the root directory

I've tried running `rake` in the root of a sample rails app I made, with WYSIHAT as a directory in the app. The rake runs fine but the framework isn't built.

So I ran `rake` in the WYSIHAT directory, and it throws

```
no such file to load -- C:/rails/myappname/wysihat/vendor/sprockets/lib/spro
ckets
```

Am I way off here? Do I need to learn Rails in order to build this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't updated the submodules.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: This also happens if you download the file from GitHub rather than `clone`ing it.